# Using an ad-hoc libc with a tool which is an argument of another tool

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I need to use a particular libc to run a tool (cp). The problem is that this tool has to be used as argument of another tool (for example timeout) and I don't want to use the modified libc with this one.

I tried to do:

```
timeout 10 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/mod/libc/ cp a b
```

But I received the error:

```
timeout: failed to run command 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/mod/libc/': No such file or directory
```

And, as I said, I can't do:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/mod/libc/ timeout 10 cp a b
```

as timeout would use the modified libc. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the [`env`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) utility:

```
timeout 10 /usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/mod/libc/ cp a b
```

Env will set the environment variable and exec the other utility with that environment.